# Drawing the lines in iphone app using touches event

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, drawing, touch

I am drawing the signatures using the touch event i have got the code from forum it works fine but problem is that it does not draw line correct like if we draw line as ali the it collapse ali in the line here is my code

here is the screen of my drawing

[image]

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:drawImage];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
mouseMoved = 0;
  }

  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImage.image = nil;
    return;
}

lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
lastPoint.y -= 20;

   }


   - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
currentPoint.y -= 20;


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

mouseMoved++;

if (mouseMoved == 10) {
    mouseMoved = 0;
}

   }

   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

  if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImage.image = nil;
    return;
  }


   if(!mouseSwiped) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
       }
           }
```

Comment: May you rephrase your problem and the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add button on pressing of that button a arrow is add on the screen and you can rotate and resize using touch.

Comment: i want that as normal person does sign it can do like this using this code